# How to delay returning a screen in BlocBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

In my app I use `flutter_bloc` for state management and in main() I use a `BlocBuilder` for the Authentication which if it receive an `Authenticated` state returns `MapScreen`, if state is `Unauthenticated` it returns the `LoginScreen`, else returns the `Splashscreen`. I'd like to control how long `Splashscreen` is displayed so I tried adding a timer in `BlocBuilder` inside state checking  but it never returns the screen. How would I set `Splashscreen` stay visible for a certain amount of time?
As always many thanks for your time and help.
This is the `BlocBuilder`:

```
home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is Unauthenticated) {
//            Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
            return LoginScreen(userRepository: _userRepository);
//            });
          }
          if (state is Authenticated) {
//            Timer(Duration(seconds: 50), () {
            return MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider<DefaultsBloc>(
                  lazy: false,
                  create: (context) => DefaultsBloc()..add(InitializeRemote()),
                ),
                BlocProvider<TrackingBloc>(
                  create: (context) => TrackingBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<DirectionsBloc>(
                  create: (context) => DirectionsBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<GeoBloc>(
                  create: (context) => GeoBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<RouteBloc>(
                  lazy: false,
                  create: (context) => RouteBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<SchedulerBloc>(
                  create: (context) => SchedulerBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<CheckerBloc>(
                  create: (context) => CheckerBloc(),
                ),
                BlocProvider<LocationBloc>(
                    lazy: false,
                    create: (context) => LocationBloc(
                          mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                        )
                          ..add(GetLocationStream())
                          ..add(GetLocation())
                          ..add(GetIsoLocationUser())),
                BlocProvider<AlertBloc>(
                  create: (context) => AlertBloc(
                      alertRepository: _alertRepository, user: state.user),
                ),
                BlocProvider<LocalNotificationBloc>(
                  lazy: false,
                  create: (context) => LocalNotificationBloc(),
                )
              ],
              child: MapScreen(
//                mapRepository: _mapRepository,
                user: state.user,
//              alertRepository: FirebaseAlertRepository(),
              ),
            );
//            });
          }
          return SplashScreen();
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to create a new event `StartApp` to be the first sent to bloc and then in bloc I set a timer to add the `AppStarted`event that starts all the authentication logic.

```
Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
      AuthenticationEvent event) async* {
    if (event is StartApp) {
      yield* _startAppToState();
    }
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      yield* _mapAppStartedToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield* _mapLoggedInToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield* _mapLoggedOutToState();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthenticationState> _startAppToState() async* {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      add(AppStarted());
    });
  }

  Stream<AuthenticationState> _mapAppStartedToState() async* {
    try {
      final isSignedIn = await _userRepository.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignedIn) {
        final user = await _userRepository.getUser();
        yield Authenticated(user);
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield Unauthenticated();
    }
  }
```

I hope this will help others.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a timer in the build method. You can create a new StatefulWidget and then add a timer in initState whcih navigates to the next screen, which will be the widget you currently have used for home.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherScreen()),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Splash'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this approach would only delay the loading of the Splash screen , what I want is to delay the others so Splasscreen stays visible longer. I'm thinking of using the Timer to delay the yielding of the states instead

Comment: You're welcome. I think this does the same thing. This shows the splash screen, and then after the duration, navigates to the other screen.

Comment: Yielding a state with a Timer didn't work. So the code in your answer  would be my Splash screen right?

Comment: Yes, you just need to make your splash screen statefull if it's not and add the timer (with the duration you want your splash screen to be visible) to `initState` method.

Comment: Ok, as I suspected this does accomplish it as the displaying of the screens is dependant  of the state received in `BlocBuilder`. As soon as a state is received it switches screen. So delaying the state is the only option I see.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you exactly mean. Do you mean you want to to show another screen when a state changes?

Comment: Yes, but with a delay. `BlocBuilder` returns as default `SplashScreen` until a state comes in and then depending on the state it returns either `LoginScreen` or `MapScreen`. SplashScreen stays visible too short as very soon a state comes in. Hope I explained it better now :)

Comment: So if you want the timer to start after a state change, you can make use of BlocListener widget. You can listen for state changes and then start the timer when the state your looking for is yield.

Comment: I solved it adding the Timer in the bloc. I created a new `StartApp` event to be the first event sent to the bloc. Upon receiving that event I set a Timer that when goes off sends the previous first event `AppStarted`, the one that triggers the whole emitting of the states logic.